# Impossible to bind toggleSwitch in a segment Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, toggle, segment

I implemented a toggle switch in a segment as follow:

```js
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left" id="menuParameter">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="default">
            <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="menu">                            
                <ion-segment-button value="segment1">
                    <ion-title> 
                        Segment1 without toggle (initialization segment)
                    </ion-title> 
                </ion-segment-button>
                <ion-segment-button value="segment2">
                    <ion-title>  
                        Segment 2 with toggle switch 
                    </ion-title>
                </ion-segment-button>
            </ion-segment> 
        </ion-toolbar>  
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>     
        <div [ngSwitch]="menu">                        
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'segment1'">
              By default here we are
        </ion-list>    
        <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'segment2'">
        <!--impossible to bind because by default i am not in segment 2 but in segment 1, so the toggle switch is not set with true value-->
                <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>There will be cake</ion-label>
                        <ion-label> {{isToggledd}} </ion-label>
                        <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="isToggled" (ionChange)="notify()"></ion-toggle>
                    </ion-item>
               
            </ion-list>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

here is my controller :

```js
export class AppComponent {
      rootPage:any = HomePage;
      public isToggled: boolean;
      public menu: string = 'segment1'; /*show segment1 by default*/                                   
      constructor(
        public platform: Platform,
        public statusBar: StatusBar) {}

        this.isToggled = true; /*toggle Switch set as TRUE*/
      public notify() {
        console.log("Toggled: "+ this.isToggled); 
      }}
```

So doing this I expect in my SEGMENT2 to have this behaviour

[image]

but the behaviour i get is the following :

[image]

BUT surprisingly, if a move the toggle switch into the segment 1, the toggle behaviour is ok :

[image]

Note the Toggle value is always "true".

any help ?

Comment: you need to put `this.isToggled = true;` inside constructor brackets `{this.isToggled = true;}`

Comment: yes i tried, but same behaviour. The toggle value is as expected "true" but the position of the toggle cursor if showed as "off"

Comment: I ran your code and it works perfect.

Comment: you are right it works in my home.html but not in my left side menu.

Comment: Just a test i made. In my left side menu, I implemented 3 toggles (true, false,false) are not initialized in my segment 2. i switch the second toggle, and then the first toggle switches to "true". I have so (true, true, false). When i click on the segment 1 and i come back to the segment 2, i have always (true, true, false) values but every toggles are in off position. Very strange

Answer (score 0):

when clicking twice on segment 2 it is ok. 
So it is possible to programmatically trigger a second click automatically (clicking a second time on segment 2 button when selected) ?